# get a record using datetime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

I have the following record:

```
[#<Availability _id: 54574c7220db9004720001d4, _type: nil, created_at: 2014-11-03 09:35:46 UTC, updated_at: 2014-11-03 09:35:46 UTC, availability_date: 2014-11-03 15:30:00 UTC, end_availability_date: 2014-11-03 16:30:00 UTC, kid_id: BSON::ObjectId('537c63ea20db9040d2000332')>]
```

I'm trying to get the record using the following code:

```
@availability = Availability.where(:availability_date.gte => DateTime.now.to_datetime.in_time_zone("Madrid")).and(:availability_date.lte => DateTime.now.to_datetime.in_time_zone("Madrid") + 20.minutes).to_a
```

I also tried:

```
@availability = Availability.where(:availability_date.gte => DateTime.now.to_datetime.in_time_zone("Madrid"), :availability_date.lte => DateTime.now.to_datetime.in_time_zone("Madrid") + 20.minutes).to_a
```

but I never get anything. What i'm doing wrong, because I have a record between this datetime.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: I don't know mongoid, but unless you want to checkout gems like squeel, the only way is to pass a syntactically legal (for your db) string to the where clause. So possibly something like `.where("availability_date >= ?", your_date)` (note: using MySQL-like syntax for demonstration purposes since I don't know how mongoid does things)

Comment: @PaulRichter Mongoid doesn't understand SQL because it works with MongoDB, the query interface is quite different.

Comment: @muistooshort Oh ok, thanks for the info. I'll have to look more closely in to that system. Ignore my comment, OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dates are always stored in UTC in the database. Why are you changing the timezone? Personally, I would use a range.

```
now = Time.current
@availability = Availability.where(availability_date: now..(20.minutes.from_now(now)))
```

or

```
now = Time.current
@availability = Availability.where(availability_date: now..(now + 20.minutes))
```